# Declare and print an Arabic character as a wchar_t

Tags: c, unicode

I'm trying to store an Arabic character as a wchar_t and then print it to the console, but can't get it to work.

I've set my console to UTF-8 and Arabic letters are displaying (albeit not joining) correctly if I just type them into the console.

I've tried a few different methods based off the answers in ([How to initialize a wchar_t variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996062/how-to-initialize-a-wchar-t-variable)) and can print out other unicode characters but not Arabic...

So far I've tried:

The code below - gives an error about making an integer from a pointer without a cast:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
    wchar_t a = L"ي";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wprintf (L" here is my character - %lc",a);


    return 0;
}
```

Same but with single quotes - runs but prints an empty space:

```
wchar_t a = L'ي';
```

The unicode value itself - gives a warning the character constant too long for its type:

```
wchar_t a = L'\xd9\x84';
```

It seems to work when I try non-Arabic characters - if I type in 'g' it comes through fine and 'xd9' gives me a nice accented U character. Is there something extra I need to do for Arabic?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Really I want to be able to type in Arabic and not have to use the unicode number.

I'm using Windows and MinGW (though I'm having problems with it anyway so would be happy to switch compilers if that solved the problem)

Comment: `wchar_t` are implementation behavior. You can't use it to handle UTF-8. You need to use a library that handle UTF-8.

Comment: hmm ok. do you know any libraries that would work?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878210/how-can-i-write-arabic-string-in-c-using-codeblocks/33879601#33879601  It might explain why your characters are not joining up.

Comment: I've tried their solutions but it still doesn't work... The problem isnt that the characters aren't  linking up but that they aren't displaying at all

Answer (score 1):

For the first example you need to use the %s format to have a chance. I haven't tried it with Arabic so I don't know what to expect. The obvious problem is that Arabic is right to left whilst consoles are designed for left to right. But printing a string as a character isn't going to work.

wchar_t is not used for UTF-8. UTF-8 uses plain char * (the main point of the encoding). wchar_t used extended 16 bit code points. If you look up the Arabic code points and enter them as numbers you should at least get Arabic output from wprintf(). To enter as Arabic glyphs is an issue with the editor as much as C++ itself.

Comment: ah ok, are wchar's considered strings then? in Arabic ي is one character

Comment: oh right i see what you mean, for consistency with the double quotes

Comment: i've tried it as a string just in case and it doesn't work

Comment: One UTF-8 character can be between 1 to 4 bytes long.

Comment: if it's more than one byte long does c consider it a string? or a character?

Comment: @Malcolm McLean I did try using the unicode number  '\xd9\x84' but it didnt work...